# Search for a numbers inside a string - Regex Python

Tags: python, regex

I am new att regex and is trying to find two numbers (sometimes with a decimal) inside a strings. The strings looks something like this:

"John Johnsson bought a house for 23 pounds (15)"

"John Johnsson bought a house for 8 pounds (11)"

"Ben Burtson bought a house for 144.5 pounds (101.5)"

"Isac Benson bought a house for 132.5 pounds (90)"

"Isac Benson bought a 2 houses for 330 pounds (110.25) together with Ben"

(What is common between the strings is "num pounds (num)")

I want to extract

[23, 15]

[144.5, 101.5]

[132.5, 90]

[330, 110.25]

Thank you for your help!
DoddelCode

Comment: Have you made an attempt at coming up with a regex for this? Are you familiar with the use of capturing groups?

Comment: What about 8 / 11, no match here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(\d+(?:\.\d+)?) pounds \((\d+(?\:.\d+)?)\)
```

`search` with this, group 1 is the number before "pounds" and group 2 is the number in the brackets.

```
>>> match = re.search(r"(\d+(?:\.\d+)?) pounds \((\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\)", "John Johnsson bought a house for 23 pounds (15)")
>>> match.group(1)
'23'
>>> match.group(2)
'15'
```

Explanation:

```
\d+(?:\.\d+)?
```

matches a number in the format you specified. `(?:)` is a non-capturing group. Everything else is pretty self-explanatory.

Try it here: https://regex101.com/r/G8gfzj/2

Comment: You should escape those dots: `\.\d+`

Comment: Thank you very much! This seems to be the code I am looking for... took me hours to try to find this out by myselfe... 5 min after I asked a question her.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
import re
s = ["John Johnsson bought a house for 23 pounds (15)", "Ben Burtson bought a house for 144.5 pounds (101.5)", "Isac Benson bought a house for 132.5 pounds (90)", "Isac Benson bought a 2 houses for 330 pounds (110.25) together with Ben"]
final_data = [re.findall('\d+\.*\d+', i) for i in s]
```

Output:

```
[['23', '15'], ['144.5', '101.5'], ['132.5', '90'], ['330', '110.25']]
```

To cast the values to either floats or integers:

```
new_data = [[int(b) if re.findall('^\d+$', b) else float(b) for b in i if b] for i in final_data]
```

Output:

```
[[23, 15], [144.5, 101.5], [132.5, 90], [330, 110.25]]
```

Edit: more robust solution:

```
import re
s = ["John Johnsson bought a house for 23 pounds (15)", "Ben Burtson bought a house for 144.5 pounds (101.5)", "Isac Benson bought a house for 132.5 pounds (90)", "Isac Benson bought a 2 houses for 330 pounds (110.25) together with Ben"]
new_s = [re.findall('\s(\d+\.*\d+)\spounds\s\((\d+\.*\d+)\)', i) for i in s]
final_s = [list(i[0]) for i in new_s if i]
```

Output:

```
[['23', '15'], ['144.5', '101.5'], ['132.5', '90'], ['330', '110.25']]
```

Comment: i think he clearly mentioned "num pounds (num)") format of extraction which you are missing